# How to refactor test application?

Tags: c#, testing, refactoring

I have a test application, with a class TestSeq and a method Go(), which consist of such blocks:

```
            _writer.WriteLine("Doing foo action...");
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            // foo - some work here
            stopwatch.Stop();
            _writer.WriteDone("Results of foo action.", stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

In "some work" I have different calls to WCF client (CRUD actions, filters, etc.).

So, a lot of code repeating, and obviously some refactor should be done here. I think about creating a class TestAction, but I dont know what is the best way to put that "some work" part in it.

It's seems to me that this is quite simple problem, but I just don't know what keywords should I search for. So, I'd be glad to see answers with just a keyword (pattern name or something) or link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure there are more, but off the top of my head, you can probably this boiler plate code in two ways.

**Method 1**: Use the using syntax to wrap the code of interest

```
class MeasuredOperation : IDisposable
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch;
    string message;

    public MeasuredOperation(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started {0}", message);
        stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Results of {0} Elapsed {1}", this.message, this.stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (new MeasuredOperation("foo action"))
        {
            // Do your action
        }
    }
```

**Method 2**: Creating a new function and passing in your block of code as a delegate

```
static void MeasuredAction(string message, Action action)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Started {0}", message);
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Results of {0} Elapsed {1}", message, stopwatch.Elapsed);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MeasureAction(delegate()
    {
        // do work
    });
}
```